# Python Code to add songs to a Spotify playlist using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, spotify

After logging in, my program starts looping over a list of songs to add them to my Spotify Playlist. But after the first loop, it raises the "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" exception.
[Link I'm working on](https://open.spotify.com/browse/featured)

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
actionChain = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get('https://open.spotify.com/browse/featured')
#Login Procedure
psw=''
login=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[2]").click()
sleep(1)
email=driver.find_element_by_id('login-username').send_keys('abc@yahoo.com')
password=driver.find_element_by_id('login-password').send_keys(psw)
login=driver.find_element_by_id('login-button').click() 

ignored_exceptions=(StaleElementReferenceException,NoSuchElementException)

def wdwfind(path):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 15,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,(path))))

def wdwclick(path):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 15,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,(path))))


for n in range(len(songs)):
    wdwfind("//li[2]/div/a/div/span").click() #going to search tab
    wdwfind("//input").send_keys(songs[n]) #sending elements to navigation bar
    gotosong=wdwclick("//a[@class='d9eb38f5d59f5fabd8ed07639aa3ab77-scss _59c935afb8f0130a69a7b07e50bac04b-scss']") #right clicking the name of the song
    actionChain.context_click(gotosong).perform()
    wdwfind("//nav/div[4]").click() #Selecting the add to playlist option
    wdwfind("//div[@class='mo-coverArt-hoverContainer']").click() #clicking on the playlist to add the song to
    sleep(2) 
    clear=wdwclick("//input[@class='_2f8ed265fb69fb70c0c9afef329ae0b6-scss']").send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.ARROW_UP) #clearing the search box
    driver.refresh()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: check your DOM is not changing because "stale element reference:" exception occurs when DOM is changed and element is not available when you are trying to perform any action on it

Comment: So could you please help me on how to move ahead with this?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: Also, what is in `songs[]`? Is this a list of strings, or something else?

Comment: `songs[]` is a list of strings. It contains songs I wish to add.

Comment: The 3rd line of loop i.e,  `gotosong` raises the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated reason behind your issue. please find solution if you are trying to add songs in playlist. You are facing above issue due to the dynamic elements in the DOM. Also after running below code I am getting membership window so cant proceed further.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# Open Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://open.spotify.com/browse/featured")





element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[2]/div/a/div/span")))
element.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='SearchInputBox__input']"))).send_keys("songs")


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Log in']").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='login-username']"))).send_keys("")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='login-password']"))).send_keys("")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='login-button']"))).click()

items = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='react-contextmenu-wrapper']/div/div/a")))
print(len(items))


for song in items:
    print song.text
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

    actionChains.context_click(song).perform()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Add to Playlist']")))
    element.click()

    element12 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn asideButton-button btn-green btn-small']")))
    actionChains.move_to_element(element12).click().perform()
    actionChains.context_click(song).perform()
    element00=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='inputBox-input']"))).send_keys("testPlayList")

    element11 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='button-group button-group--horizontal']//div[2]/button")))
    actionChains.move_to_element(element11).click().perform()

    elem=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='TrackListHeader__entity-name']//span")))
    print elem.text
    break
```

Comment: I have edited the code which will help you move ahead from the membership window.

Comment: I will accept your answer but could you first help me with adding songs to the playlist. `songs=['I Want It that way','Believer']`. I wish to add these songs to the playlist but DOM refreshes after the first run. If you would help me to prevent DOM from changing or some other alternative, I'd be grateful to you.

Comment: Dear Dipak, You seem to have misunderstood me. Your code is adding all the song suggestions which appear during the search of one specific song. But I intend to send 100 songs one by one in the search query and add the first result of each search to the playlist. If possible, please get in touch with me at mehta_priyesh7401@yahoo.com so that I can better explain my objectives.

Comment: My code is finally working. I learnt many new things from your code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry @PriyeshMehta I was facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914348/driver-info-driver-version-unknown-using-chromedriver-v78-0-3904-97-chrome-v78/58917636?noredirect=1#comment104102207_58917636 issue and struggling to sort it out, so did not get chance to amend above code but glad to hear you sort it out