# Driver info: driver.version: unknown using ChromeDriver v78.0.3904.70 and Chrome browser v78.0.3904.97

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using java 1.8 with chrome browser version `78.0.3904.97`. I am trying to execute my selenium script code with the chrome driver version `78.0.3904.70`. but while execution I am facing below issue and chrome crases immediately

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

If you check the below logs then you will get to know that I am passing 78.0.3904.70 version of chrome driver and trying to launch 78.0.3904.97 chrome browser which is creating an issue. Also if you check `https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads` link then you will get to know 78.0.3904.97 version of chrome driver is not available

**Error Log**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 22844
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Nov 18, 2019 12:06:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
12:06:32.350 [main] DEBUG net.serenitybdd.core.photography.Darkroom - Opening darkroom
12:06:32.360 [Darkroom Processing Line] DEBUG net.serenitybdd.core.photography.DarkroomProcessingLine - Darkroom processing line starting up
12:06:33.613 [main] DEBUG net.serenitybdd.core.photography.Darkroom - Send negative for processing for target\site\serenity\c5e0d5f762dd0408b347b1b56ece2682cce0d422c500276e3f33c78c87fadcf6.png
12:06:35.280 [main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - 


12:06:35.825 [main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - TEST FAILED AT STEP Launch browser and navigate to  URL
12:06:35.825 [main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - invalid argument



org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'UKF6-L015064', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 78.0.3904.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de024..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DIPAK~1.BAC\AppDat...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52359}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 22ece16d3a54371674e778dca702876b
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'UKF6-L015064', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

    at webapplication.contactlenses.pages.Homepage.navigateToBaseUrlNL(Homepage.java:530)
    at webapplication.contactlenses.steplib.ContactLensSteplib.navigate_to_baseUrlNL(ContactLensSteplib.java:28)
    at webapplication.contactlenses.steplib.ContactLensSteplib$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$916d3a70.CGLIB$navigate_to_baseUrlNL$16(<generated>)
    at webapplication.contactlenses.steplib.ContactLensSteplib$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$916d3a70$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c8d6c80f.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:461)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:446)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:421)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(StepInterceptor.java:176)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:163)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:69)
    at webapplication.contactlenses.steplib.ContactLensSteplib$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$916d3a70.navigate_to_baseUrlNL(<generated>)
```

I have already checked for chrome driver version `78.0.3904.97` but it's not available. Can someone please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you able to execute the `.exe` file for Chromedriver itself by clicking on it?

Comment: If you check log chrome is launching properly but it's immediately  crashes

Comment: Have you tried with the beta version for 79? If it also fails then there is something else/

Comment: No,  I am on cooperate proxy and cant downgrade or upgrade my chrome

Comment: Does you chrome browser launches? Maybe you can check if you are passing correct url with 'http://' . From the logs, it is not clear why it is failing. Maybe you will be required to share the code as well

Comment: It's not with code. I am 100% sure if you check then I am passing 78.0.3904.70 version of chrome driver and trying to launch 78.0.3904.97 chrome browser which is creating an issue. Also if you check https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads link then you will get to know 78.0.3904.97 version of chrome driver is not available

Answer (score 0):

Chromedriver version should be shown in logs

```
 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Are you setting the correct path to chromedriver.exe. Verify it.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/PathToChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Yes I am pretty much sure its there

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'UKF6-L015064', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 78.0.3904.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de024..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DIPAK~1.BAC\AppDat...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52359}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 22ece16d3a54371674e778dca702876b
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'UKF6-L015064', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though you are using *chromedriver=78.0.3904.97*
- And you are also using *chrome=78.0.3904.97*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is also *3.141.59*.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* , *Selenium Client v3.141.59* , *ChromeDriver v78.0.3904.97* and the *Chrome Browser v78.0.3904.97*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Comment: @DipakBachhav Your comment doesn't helps me either. Sorry, the answer didn't help you to solve your problem but how am I going to improve my post with that feedback?

Comment: Please don't take it negatively but i  have tried all your solution and struggling very badly from past 9 hours to resolve this issue if I accept your answer then i will not get answer. hope you can understand and sorry once again

Comment: @DipakBachhav There is absolutely nothing to take _positive_ or _negative_ from a canonical answer and those words are considered as typical **noise** as stackoverflow standards. You need to update the question with the observations (modified code block and new set of error stack trace) for further analysis.

Comment: Actually, this was an incredibly useful answer. +1 from me

Comment: @BrandonWard It's my utmost effort to provide the best content to help the community. Your words brings a lot of encouragement. Thanks